# object parameter in async TypeScript method becomes undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I will start saying this is my first project in TypeScript coming from 5+ years in Java, so forgive me if the question is too obvious. I have been unable to identify why this behaviour is happening.

I have a the following TypeScript file (SendEvent.ts):

```
export default async function SendEvent (entityName: string, entityId: string, eventName: string, payload: object): Promise<PutEventResponse> {
    console.log("Sending %o payload from %s entity with uuid %s", payload, entityName + entityId, uuid());

    //OTHER CODE NOT RELEVANT, SINCE PROBLEM IS ABOVE
}
```

I have another file inside a test AWS Lambda, which imports and call the method SendEvent:

```
import {SendEvent} from 'my-node-dependency';



export const handler = async(event) => {
    const payload = {dateString:"2023/02/03", description:"Test"};
    
    console.log("Object: %o", payload); //Logs: Object: {dateString:"2023/02/03", description:"Test"}
    console.log("%o", SendEvent);  //Logs: [AsyncFunction: SendEvent] ...
    const result = await SendEvent("TESTENTITY", "1", "EntityTested", payload)
    .then((data) => data);
    //...
    return response;
};
```

To my surprise, the log line in SendEvent.ts file logs

`Sending undefined payload from TESTENTITY1 entity with uuid 8c332903-10ae-4019-8e81-88b54f18d18d`

Why does the payload parameter on the SendEvent method becomes undefined? Same happens if
`payload = "someValue";`

Tried changing the value of payload to a primitive (string, number), but same `undefined` result.
When debugging in local environment from a test class inside the same directory as SendEvent.ts file everything works well.

```
import { SendEvent, PutEventResponse } from '../dir_where_SendEvent.js_transpiled_file_is';

const payload: object = {someField: "someValue", someOtherField: 1};
const entityName: string = "someEntity";
const entityId: string = "1";
const eventName: string = "testEvent";

const putEventResponse: Promise<PutEventResponse> = SendEvent(entityName, entityId, eventName, payload);
```

Thank you!